# How to use a vector (array) in a function parameter on Arduino code?

Tags: arrays, function, vector, arduino

How do I use a vector (array) in a function parameter on Arduino code?

My example (doesn't work)

```cpp
void teste(int vetor[], int variavel)
{
    // code
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code you show.

Remember, there's no such thing as an "Arduino language" -- [it's all just C++ (see my answer here)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/816/c-vs-the-arduino-language/50839#50839) (at least C++11 (ie: C++ 2011 version), but could be a later version of C++, depending on your board). And, C is, for the most part, a 99.9% subset of C++. What you are trying to do here is use a C-style or C array as a function parameter.

So, sample Google searches that would work well to help you include:

1. [arduino array](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+array&oq=arduino+array&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2j69i65j69i60.1841j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

   1. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/
2. [c array](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+array&oq=c+array&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i65l2j69i60j69i65j69i60l2.1238j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. [pass array and size to function in c](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+array+and+size+to+function+in+c&oq=pass+array+and+size+to+function+in+c&aqs=chrome..69i57.6505j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

   1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Here's a full, working example. Run it online here: https://onlinegdb.com/Skds3AYk_.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

// Get the number of elements in any C array
// - source: [my repo] https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/utilities.h#L20
// - Usage example: [my own answer]:
//   https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80236/initializing-array-of-structs/80289#80289
#define ARRAY_LEN(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

/// \brief      A test function to print all the elements of an array 
/// \param[in]  array       An array of ints 
/// \param[in]  size        The number of elements in the array 
/// \return     None
void test(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("array[i] = %i\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    int my_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    test(my_array, ARRAY_LEN(my_array));

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```cpp
> Hello World
> array[i] = 1
> array[i] = 2
> array[i] = 3
> array[i] = 4
> array[i] = 5
> array[i] = 6
> ```

Just remember that in Arduino you should use `Serial.print()` instead of `printf()`, since it is a microcontroller platform and they haven't overridden `printf()` to route it to the serial output.

### References:

1. [Source of `ARRAY_LEN()` macro (my repo)](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/utilities.h#L20)
2. Usage example of `ARRAY_LEN()` macro: [my own answer]: [Arduino Stack Exchange: Initializing Array of structs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80236/initializing-array-of-structs/80289#80289)